# How to request Android runtime permissions(OS 6+) from within fragment lifecycle method

Tags: android, android-fragments, blocking, lifecycle, runtime-permissions

I have a fragment-based app (using "targetSdkVersion 23") that executes code within some of the fragment lifecycle methods that requires dangerous permissions. 
The OS 6 permissions framework involves permissions acceptance via a callback before the app can proceed to execute the code that actually requires the permissions.
It seems the OS 6 permissions model does not provide a synchronous mode, and there is a bunch of code that is currently being executed (pre-Marshmallow) inside the lifecycle method that depends on the dangerous permission.
This new callback requirement will break my existing code because the main thread will be forced to proceed to executing the next lifecycle method without having completed executing the logic in the previous lifecycle method (!) due to the asynchronous nature of callbacks; this execution dislocation will create issues downstream in the code.

If I apply blocking techniques(BlockingQueue, CountDownLatch, etc.) in the main thread, it seems that will also prevent the callback from ever happening.

Can anyone suggest a technique or coding model that will allow me to request and obtain runtime permissions without breaking the current app and without a massive re-architecting of the fragments app?

PS. it's a Java8-based app.

Comment: you have to move all the logic that needs permission to outside the lifecycle method and call if from the callback instead.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the sequence of logic execution is required *during* the lifecycle methods; the code initializes several things required by the fragment. The callback's context does not seem to be the right place/time to execute that code.

Comment: Without code there's little others can help. The way of doing it is by removing from the lifecycle. You won't be able to execute it synchronously, any attempt to block the execution your app will be reported as not working by the system. You have to rethink how you're doing it

Comment: Thnx. I realize that blocking execution within a lifecycle method is very much frowned upon but I was hoping that heavy code refactoring was not the only solution.